# Having trouble making JSON parse and eval to work in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

As I stated above, I have a PHP script and a JavaScript, I have a few objects that read text files on the server side and then pass the data to the JavaScript.

Here's my entire code:

map.html:  http://www.pastebin.com/b45mbvgp and index.php:  http://www.pastebin.com/zibdquzu

The part that really matters:

```
var x = <?php echo json_encode($streetsObject); ?>;
var obj = eval("("x")");
```

I've also tried

```
var obj = JSON.parse(x);
```

the X variable does get set to the size of the passed object, 527 (tested it) but when I try to use the eval or JSON parse function is simply doesn't work. Do I have some sort of mistake in my html code which is messing with my calls to other libraries? If so that would be weird because kinetic.js is working just fine. I've been googling examples of JSON and I have yet to see an example of parsing a passed object, it's all examples of local objects :(

(Code works fine if I remove eval / json line of code)

Comment: Have yout tried console.log(x)?

Comment: `x` is *already* an object.  No need to parse it.  JSON strings are subsets of JavaScript syntax, so it's read as an object.

Comment: Understanding basic JS strings syntax (or even basic strings syntax in any language) would've told you that `"("x")"` couldn't possibly be valid...

Comment: @RagenDazs console.log(x) or just console.log doesn't display anything, alert seems to show up basic messages though such as "hi" etc. Not sure why log isn't working though.

Ohh i see how i can see it now, sorry I learned javascript etc through codeacadamy didn't realize i had to use ctrl shift j

Comment: @oorosco What do you mean it is not working? Have you checked the console? (Ctrl+Shift+J in Chrome for example)

Comment: Edit your post and put the contents of `echo json_encode($streetsObject);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply do:

```
var obj = <?php echo json_encode($streetsObject); ?>;
```

JSON means JavaScript Object Notation. If you insert JSON directly to Javascript, it will run fine, just in this case. No parsing needed. `eval` is not recommended to use for JSON parsing, but the same applies to that (note that `eval` actually works because JSON is valid Javascript!).

`JSON.parse` is only needed if you have JSON in a Javascript string. So this would work:

```
var str = '<?php echo json_encode($streetsObject); ?>';
var obj = JSON.parse(str);
```

Comment: Alright so how do I get the elements of the object on the javascript side?
    php side: $streetsObject[x]->streetArray[y]->x_

Comment: @oorosco Just add `console.log(obj);` after my example code and see (check in the Javascript console, object properties will be listed). I don't know what is in your object, but `obj` will be an absolutely valid Javascript object, containing the same data as your JSON.

Comment: alright thanks for the clarification, I really didn't get this out of the examples online thanks I'll check mark this in a sec just want to make sure it all works :D